# Loading Animations in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm attempting to get a few animations going at the start of an activity, specifically some smiley faces that should fade in, along with another imageview and textview. However doing all of this at onCreate predictably causes my application to freeze, So I've attempted to move all the animations to an AsyncTask and execute it on create.

here is where I call the animations:

```
public class Animtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
Animation fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
_view.startAnimation(fadein);
_view2.startAnimation(fadein);
_view3.startAnimation(fadein);
_view4.startAnimation(fadein);
_view5.startAnimation(fadein);
guide.startAnimation(fadein);
blender.startAnimation(fadein);
}
}
```

Eclipse seems to agree with everything else, but  loadAnimation is causing issues, suggesting that the method isn't applicable for the arguments. Can anyone see at a glance where I have gone horribly wrong? I'll post anything else if you believe it to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Animation fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
```

The `this` keyword here refers to the `Animtask` class you've created by extending `AsyncTask`, but the `loadAnimation` method wants an object of `Context` class. Assuming the class name of your activity is MyActivity, you can probably solve the compilation error by changing the above line to

```
Animation fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
```

**However, the `doInBackground` method in an `AsyncTask` is not suppose to touch the UI thread, so you will probably get into this error when you try to run this AsyncTask.** Is the slowdown really caused by the animation only, or it is caused by loading the resources (images) of the animation? A solution maybe to move the animation calls to the `onPostExecute` method, and to load the resources on the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Honestly it's more to test if it is the problem, I'll get back to you if this works or not.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, and more testing revealed it may not be the issue at all, as the textview and imageview both freeze up the app either way, so I must have defined them differently to the others, which might be the issue.